# Why does this work even though the function is not called with a pointer to a pointer as a parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, bitmap, msdn, direct2d

In a code from MSDN, there is this:

```
HRESULT DemoApp::LoadBitmapFromFile(
    ID2D1RenderTarget *pRenderTarget,
    IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory,
    PCWSTR uri,
    UINT destinationWidth,
    UINT destinationHeight,
    ID2D1Bitmap **ppBitmap
    )
```

And this:

```
hr = LoadBitmapFromFile(
                m_pRenderTarget,
                m_pWICFactory,
                L".\\sampleImage.jpg",
                100,
                0,
                &m_pBitmap
                );
```

How comes it works when m_pBitmap actually is a pointer to an ID2D1Bitmap object (ID2D1Bitmap *m_pBitmap) instead of a pointer to a pointer to an ID2D1Bitmap object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the argument being passed is not `m_pBitmap`, but `&m_pBitmap`.

If `m_pBitmap` is a `ID2D1Bitmap*` then when you take the address of it with `&`, you get a `ID2D1BitMap**` - a pointer to a pointer, just as the function expects.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the address of a pointer makes it a pointer to a pointer.

```
int i = 0;
int *pi = &i // &i is the address of i (or a pointer to the int i)
&pi // &pi is the address of pi (or a pointer to the pointer to i)
```

So, `&m_pBitmap` makes a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the address of a pointer makes the parameter pointer to pointer which is exactly the type.